# how to create multiple things saved in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have some code which allows me to get data from the user and gets saved locally but doesn't make a new item in local storage for each set of inputs. 
It currently save s the data but only until you delete it or overwrites it
How do I make it so it creates a new storage item rather than overwriting it?

```
 let reminders = [];

const addReminders = (ev) => {
 ev.preventDefault(); 
let reminder = {
ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value

}

const arr = [reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]

localStorage.setItem('todoForm', JSON.stringify(arr))

 localStorage.getItem('todoForm', JSON.parse(arr))

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addReminders);
});


<div class="container">
    <!-- The above form looks like this -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns" style="margin-top: 20%">
            <form id="todoForm">
                <label for="ReminderInput">Reminder</label>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="ReminderInput">


                <label for="DateInput">Date</label>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="datetime-local" id="DateInput">


                <label for="InfoInput">Additional Information</label>
                <textarea class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Remember to..." id="InfoInput"></textarea>
                <button type="button" id="btn" class="button-primary">Add Reminder</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: i hope u want to save multiple items in localstorage without overwritting it ?

Comment: @EaGLE yes I want to save multiple items in localstorage without overwriting it as it is a reminder checklist that I need to be able to add multiple things to

Answer (score 1):

In localstorage, the items are identified by their names. If you save two different objects with the same name, the last one will overwrite the first, as you've seen.

In this circumstance, it may be better to keep a list of all the reminders (or get it from the localstorage), add the new one to the list and save the whole list.

```
let reminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("reminders"));

// ...

reminders.push([reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]);
localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
```

Comment: Just realised that if I refresh the page it doesn't save the previous reminder list. What do I need to change to keep it all the time as I will want it to remember everything

Comment: Localstorage should'nt automatically erase data on refresh...  try checking that the list is actually saved in local storage using the developer tools of your browser. In chrome you can find this information in the "application" tab of the developer tools. Also, check that you are using JSON.stringify within localstorage setitem

Comment: yes it does show in under the local storage but you refresh and add a new reminder it deletes what was there rather than adding to it

Comment: I just tested the code and it's working even after a page refresh. I would suggest you to look and make sure that you are getting the variable from localstorage before doing any addition. Also, check that the key name of the item you get from localstorage is the same key name of the one you save. It is probably an error in the rest of the code, try debugging it with devtools, if you need help in doing it, this is a tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should store the object inside the array:

```
// getItem will return a string, so you have to parse in this way:
const storedJson = localStorage.getItem('todoForm');
const reminders = storedJson ? JSON.parse(storedJson) || [];

// into the array you should store object, not single data:
function addReminders(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const reminder = {
        ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
        DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
        InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value
    };
    reminders.push(reminder);

    updateStorage();
}

function updateStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
}
```

In this way the data will be more clear and you'll have an easier access to it.

Comment: do I need to replace any of the code const reminders = storedJson ? JSON.parse(storedJson) || [];

Comment: Yes, you should, when you call `localStorage.getItem('todoForm')` it can returns the same string that was stored previously into the `localStorage` at the key `todoForm`, if no strings was stored it will return `null`.

P.S.: If this solution works for you, you should mark this as good solution, not the first one received. This will help the other users to understand what's the solution to adopt if they have your same issue.

Comment: not sure if I've done it wrong or what but the code doesn't seem to work so would you be able to edit the code so it has the entire javascript and maybe add comments to where I need to edit it

Comment: What's the part that is not working? You should consider that the code I written update the `reminders` array but it doesn't show the result anywhere and you can see the complete value just into the developer tool. Obviously if you need to show it into the html document (to the user) you have to decide where and how. The instructions to show those data was not included in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
 let reminders = [];
let arr;

const addReminders = (ev) => {
 ev.preventDefault(); 
let reminder = {
ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value
}
    if(localStorage.getItem("todoForm") === null){ //check if localstorage is empty
     arr=[]; 
    }else{
      arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoForm"); 
      //if it already has elements,it will set 'arr' to the elements of localStorage
    })
    arr.push(reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput); //push your new elements
    localStorage.setItem('todoForm', JSON.stringify(arr))
    localStorage.getItem('todoForm', JSON.parse(arr))
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addReminders);
}
```

For example if ur local storage consists of a array like this:

```
['todo1','todo2','todo3']; //array 1
```

when you are setting the localStorage with new todo items like

```
['todo4','todo5']
```

The previous wont get replaced because."array1" will be retrived to 'arr'.like this

```
arr = ['todo1','todo2','todo3']; //from localStorage;
```

later you push your new elements 'todo4','todo5';
the arr becomes

```
arr = ['todo1','todo2','todo3','todo4','todo5'];
```

It is basically retriving the elements from localStorage to an array and adding new elements to the array and set localStorage with the modified array,like this you wont overwrite your existing elements

Comment: sorry for the late response but where do I add this to my code? could you give me entire javascript I need?

Comment: i will edit the answer according to ur request .. check it

Answer (score 0):

Here is whole example you just need to oranize your data as you well.

Important this example dont work on code snippet becouse :

> Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window':  The
>   document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Test on : [codepenio](https://codepen.io/zlatnaspirala/pen/pojVdyQ?editors=1111)

```js
/**
 * LocalStorageMemory save and load js objects in localStorage.
 */
var localStorageMemory = {
  localStorage: window.localStorage,
  /**
   * save  Put the object into storage.
   * @example Usage : save("MyObjectKey", myObject )
   * @method save
   * @param {String} Name Name of localstorage key
   * @param {object} Value Any object we can store.
   * @return {false | object} What ever we are stored intro localStorage.
   */
  save: function(name, obj) {
    try {
      return localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Something wrong in LocalStorageMemory class , method save! -> ", e);
      return false;
    }
  },
  /**
   * Load saved object from storage. Retrieve the object from storage or
   * return false.
   * @example Usage : var giveMeMyObject = load("MyObjectKey")
   * @function load
   * @param {String} Name Name of localstorage key
   * @return {false | object} What ever we are stored intro localStorage.
   */
  load: function(name) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(name) === "undefined" || localStorage.getItem(name) == null || localStorage.getItem(name) === "") {
      console.warn("LocalStorageMemory method load return's: ", localStorage.getItem(name));
      return false;
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
    }
  }
}



/**********CREATE INSTANCE***********/

var saveAnyDataObj = {
  name: "wins",
  numberOfWins: c++
};

localStorageMemory.save("MyObject1", saveAnyDataObj);



var getMyMemory = localStorageMemory.load("MyObject1");
console.log("MyObject1 = ", getMyMemory);

var c = 0;

setInterval(function() {

var saveAnyDataObj = {
  name: "wins",
  numberOfWins: c++
};

localStorageMemory.save("MyObject1", saveAnyDataObj);

getMyMemory = localStorageMemory.load("MyObject1");
  
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getMyMemory.numberOfWins;
}, 1000);
```